# Get text from another application in objective-c / Applescript "AXTextArea"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, gettext

I need to access the text inside an "AXTextArea", I have no problems doing the same in Windows using the win32api to find the window, then its child window, drilling down and finding what I need and running a getText to that child.

I am learning objective-c and I was wondering how I would go about doing the same on a Mac?

I have had a look with the accessibility inspector and I have found the correct area I need:

[image: Inspector Information]

The main application name is: "BlackJack"(AXApplication)

Separate Window opened within the application: "BlackJack Tournament 223"(AXWindow:AXStandardWindow)

AXScrollArea has 2 children (AXTextArea) which I want and a scrollbar.

How do I "Find the window" in objective-c and then find/enumerate their children and finally use a send text to grab the string data?

Sorry if my post seems too windows-esque!

Comment: You can't do this in Objective-C. You can do this in C using the Accessibility API. Or you can do this in AppleScript using the Processes Suite of System Events.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example please? if using applescript can you incorporate it into obj-c like you can with python using OSAscript?

Comment: Discovered how to use OSAscript with obj-c and get the results, now I just need to play around with applescript to see if I can find how to grab that text.

Comment: It will be something like `tell application "System Events" to get value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "BlackJack Tournament"`